# Should resource ids be present in urls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, rest

In situations where the resource id can be identified by other means (such as current_user for pages that require authentication), is it a good idea to omit the id from the url? (For example, `/students/1/homework` to `/students/homework`).

Also, would this have any impact on the restfulness of the urls? I am suspecting it does for HTTP verbs, but for custom actions I am not so sure.

Comment: Also consider the `/students/current/homework` alternative.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it is down to your application and what is useful for clients to see.  If your connecting user is an admin who can see all students homework, then the `/students/1/homework` path makes sense, however if it will only ever be students using this resource then the `/students/homework` makes more sense.
Essentially the latter could be thought of as a `namespace` for all student resources.
I have found it very useful to split these resources by `namespaces` as to not confuse client writers and keep your authorisation very clear (who can see/do what).

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the 2 URIs identify different resources:

- the homework of user #1,
- the homework of the current user.

The choice depends a lot on which resource you think people will want to refer to (by e-mail or by bookmark for example).

I don't think the second solution is unRESTful, but I would prefer the first one, since it is compatible with a lot of additional features (e.g. teachers could access the representation of students' homework).

Answer (score 1):

URLs should always point to one specific resource. They can either be absolute or relative. Think of it as a filesystem. In some cases (security/scalability) you can't allow listings.

- **Session-based / Relative resources** `/students/me`, `/students/latest`, `/students/latest/homework/lastest`
- **Absolute resources** `/students/3`, `/students/3/homework`, `/teachers/3/homework/3`